# Insert document in Cosmos DB using PowerShell (SQL API) using azure Devops CLI Task

Tags: azure-devops

I have received the below error while executing my code in azureCLI task of azuredevops:

> New-CosmosDbContext : The term 'New-CosmosDbContext' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet,

what is the step to solve this or any other suggestion for insert a document in cosmosDB Container using azure CLI task in Azure Devops?

```
$resourceGroupName = 'rg-****'
$accountName = 'cosmosserver-****'
$databaseName = 'DefaultSystemDB'
$OrganisationName = "SampleOrg"
$ContractName = 'SampleContract'
$TypeName = 'SampleType"
$currentDate = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
write-Host $currentDate    
$containerName = 'Organisation'
$partitionKey = '/id'
$cosmosDbContext = New-CosmosDbContext -Account $accountName -Database $databaseName -ResourceGroup $resourceGroupName
$Organisationid='$([Guid]::NewGuid().ToString())'
write-Host Organisationid: $Organisationid    
$document = @"
{
        "Name": '$OrganisationName',       
        "CreatedOn": '$currentDate',
        "id":  '$Organisationid'
}
"@
$partitionkey = '$Organisationid'
New-CosmosDbDocument -Context $cosmosDbContext -CollectionId $containerName -DocumentBody $document -PartitionKey $partitionkey
```

Answer (score 1):

Please install the CosmosDB Module first. The module is not in the hosted agent by default. Please add the following at the beginning of your script. It may need some minutes to install it.

```
Install-Module -Name CosmosDB -force
```

Edit:

In your script,  you are using the `New-CosmosDbContext`. So you should install the CosmosDB Module instead of  Az.CosmosDB Module . Please refer https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB#installation.

If you want to use the Az.CosmosDB Module , please use  `New-AzCosmosDBxxxxxx` . See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/?view=azps-8.1.0 for more detail.

Comment: i tried this. but same error only.
"Install-Module  Az.CosmosDB -Scope CurrentUser -Force"

Comment: Hi , please check my answer again, I have edited it and added more info.